# Having trouble Merging 2 subtitle blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, subtitle

I'm trying to merge 2 subtitle blocks for easier translation use for deepl. While the sentences can be merged and end time changed I'm having trouble changing the index numbers. The count variable is incremented but never substracted from the index.

For example if we have this subtitle block:

```
5
00:00:23,315 --> 00:00:25,108
A streetwise but soulful
teen needed somewhere to live

6
00:00:25,192 --> 00:00:26,610
as he waited for his Juilliard audition.

7
00:00:26,693 --> 00:00:29,488
We'd support his dancing and let
him stay in the guest room, right.
```

5 and 6 are going to be merged. The end time will that of 6. That workjs well except when it's merged it's i should get indexes of 5 and 6 but instead I get 5 and 7.

Example of what i'm trying to make:

```
5
00:00:23,315 --> 00:00:26,610
A streetwise but soulful
teen needed somewhere to live
as he waited for his Juilliard audition.

6
00:00:26,693 --> 00:00:29,488
We'd support his dancing and let
him stay in the guest room, right.
```

This is my code. I tried adding 2 places, tried `subs[sub.index].index = subs[sub.index] - count` but none of that worked.

```
import pysrt
import os

count = 0

# Init pysrt
subs = pysrt.open(" Bojack Horseman36.srt")
# Go through each subtitle
for sub in subs:
    try:
        # Check if it's a sentence if not check if there is another sentence there if not nothing just remove index
        sentence = None
        if subs[sub.index].text.endswith('.') or subs[sub.index].text.endswith('?') or subs[sub.index].text.endswith('!'):
            subs[sub.index].index - count
        else:
            subs[sub.index].text = subs[sub.index].text + '\n' + subs[sub.index+1].text
            count+=1
            subs[sub.index].index - count
            subs[sub.index].end = subs[sub.index+1].end
            del subs[sub.index+1]
    except IndexError:      
        pass

subs.save('translatedsubs.srt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Any help is going to be appreciated thanks :D

Comment: Could you include what the merged output should actually look like, this would make it a lot clearer to understand.

Comment: @MartinEvans check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
import pysrt

subs = pysrt.open("test.srt")
append_index = None
remove_list = []                # List of unwanted indexes
sub_index = subs[0].index       # Existing starting index

for index, sub in enumerate(subs):
    if append_index is not None:
        subs[append_index].text += "\n" + sub.text
        subs[append_index].end = sub.end
        remove_list.append(index)
    if sub.text[-1] not in '.?!':
        append_index = index
    else:
        append_index = None

# Remove orphaned subs in reverse order        
for index in remove_list[::-1]:     
    del subs[index]

# Reindex remaining subs
for index in range(len(subs)):
    subs[index].index = index + sub_index

subs.save('test out.srt', encoding='utf-8')
```

It might though run into issues if there are multiple joins required in a row.

It produces the following output:

```
5
00:00:23,315 --> 00:00:26,610
A streetwise but soulful
teen needed somewhere to live
as he waited for his Juilliard audition.

6
00:00:26,693 --> 00:00:29,488
We'd support his dancing and let
him stay in the guest room, right.
```

Note, it is best not to remove or add items in a list that is being iterated over. Instead I create a list of indexes to be removed. Afterwards unwanted indexes are deleted in reverse order, that way the index of the remaining items to be removed remains the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinEvans couldn't done it without you! :D

Comment: You could use subs.clean_indexes() to reindex the subs